# How do I use a child object as if it is a parent object?

Tags: java

I've got a set of Java classes I'm using as a toolkit that I can plug into many projects.  I do not want to change the code in this toolkit, so that any time I update it or fix a bug, I can just drop it into any of my projects that are using it, without needing to worry about local changes.  Thus, if any local projects need to override a method in the toolkit, I just make a local version of the toolkit object, like such:

**FILE:  toolkit/Dog()**

```
public class Dog(){
  public void pet(){
    print("scratch ruff");
  }
}
```

**FILE:  local/Dog()**

```
public class Dog extends toolkit/Dog {
  public void pet(){
    print("rub ears");
  }
}
```

And in the local objects, I refer to the local `Dog` object instead of the toolkit `Dog` object.

This so far has worked great, but I just ran into an issue.  Another class in the toolkit uses `Dog`.

**FILE:  toolkit/DogHandler**

```
public void careForPack( List<Dog> arg_allTheDogs ){
  for( Dog fido : arg_allTheDogs ){
    fido.pet();
  }
}
```

The problem that arises is that the system doesn't like that these are not the same `Dog` object.  I don't want to locally override `DogHandler`, because I'll just end up overriding my entire toolkit, which rather defeats the purpose.

Is there a way for the `DogHandler` to recognize `Dog`'s child, also called `Dog`, as being valid?

Comment: Qualify it by full class name... <local package name>.Dog should do the trick for you.

Comment: `public void careForPack( List<toolkit.Dog> arg_allTheDogs ){`?

Comment: I figure he wants to use toolkit.dog in method signature but actual, local dog in method body.

Comment: I was not clear enough. In the local code, I need to call toolkit.DogHandler.careForPack( ) with a List<local.Dog> argument and have it work.

Comment: Is it sufficient that the elements in the list *extend* `toolkit/Dog`? In that case, you can use `List<? extends Dog> arg_allTheDogs`.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens even better than what we had :)

Comment: ALWAYS paste the error message you get and the code causing the error whan you ask a question about a compile or runtime error.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens - that was very useful.  Can't figure out how to upvote you ...

Comment: @JB Nizet - thank you.  I'll remember that next time.

Comment: @mipe34 Thank you for improving the formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make your toolkit method accept a `List` containing objects of a type that *extends* `toolkit.Dog`. You can use `? extends T` for this:

```
public void careForPack( List<? extends toolkit.Dog> arg_allTheDogs ){
  for( toolkit.Dog fido : arg_allTheDogs ){
    fido.pet();
  }
}
```

Comment: not what was asked. He needs the careForPack to use local dog... I'd suggest an interface rather than runtime datatype evaluation...

Comment: I derped, I wrote `super` where I meant `extends`. Thanks for the ninja edit, @JBNizet! :)

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot.  Implemented it, and it works.  Can't upvote till I get 15 rep, but I would if I could!

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Hrm.  Of course, now I need to also return a `List<Dog>` from a different `DogHandler` method ... which looks like I need to use factories... If you have suggestions for where to look for that, I'd be quite happy.

Comment: @WolfmanJoe Well, how is that list going to be produced? If you need to create new `Dog`s, then you'll indeed need some kind of factory class. You can however define it generically `DogFactory<T>` with `T extends Dog` so it produces a `T`. If you need more help or support, just make a new question. :-)

Comment: @MattiasBuelens - I never did say 'thank you' for this last suggestion - it took a day or two of wrangling, but I did end up figuring it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void careForPack( List<toolkit.Dog> arg_allTheDogs )
{
   for( local.package.name.Dog fido : arg_allTheDogs )
   {
       fido.pet();
   }
}
```

EDIT: maybe this?

```
//we need an interface to have datatype interchangability
public class Toolkit.Dog implements IToolkitDog
{
    public void pet()
    {
        print("toolkit dog says what");
    }
}

//we inherit the IToolkitDog from Toolkit.Dog
public class local.Dog extends Toolkit.Dog 
{
     public void pet()
     {
         print("rub ears");
     }
}


//both toolkit.dog and local.dog are of type IToolkitDog 
public void careForPack( List<IToolkitDog> arg_allTheDogs )
{
    for( local.Dog fido : arg_allTheDogs )
    {
       fido.pet();
    }
}
```

can this do the trick?

I guess it'll look like this

```
public interface IToolkitDog
{
     pet();
//...
}
```

Comment: I was not clear enough. In the local code, I need to call toolkit.DogHandler.careForPack( ) with a List<local.Dog> argument and have it work.

Comment: ooooh, sounds like you want closures; you want to locally override toolkit.DogHandler.careForPack() to use your local.Dog instead of toolkit.Dog ?

Wait for Java7, or interface that code.

Comment: Like, instead of simply extending Dog, make an interface IToolkitDog, implement it by Local Dog and change your handler to use List<IToolkitDog> instead of List<toolkit.Dog> ... that will enable you to use both Toolkit Dog and local dog.

Comment: No, it won't. Using an interface will lead to exactly the same problem. And closures have nothing to do with that. And Java 7 is out for a long time. As explained by Mattias Buelens in comments, the argument should simply be a `List<? extends Dog>`.